# Any issues using SQL Server 2008 R2 backup on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, compatibility, sql-server-2014

Our website is backed by a database written using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.  I am in India working with an outsource org and the only thing they can get is SQL server 2014 developer edition, which supports the compression options that are used with 2008 r2 enterprise.  I have verified on my box that I can install 2014 developer, attach the mdf of the 2008 r2 database which gets set to 2008 compatibility, launch our site and everything appears to work.  But I am concerned about potential issues if the database behaves in an unexpected way in 2014.  The biggest issue I've read about is if TSQL code is written against a server running in compatibility mode, that may not behave as expected after it is deployed to the server running the actual version being emulated.  These guys aren't going to be doing any database work, just website work, so that part may be of no concern. With that in mind, what are potential issues that we might run into?

Comment: Going from 2008 R2 to 2014 should not cause any issues - but the other way back is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going forward with MS SQL backups has never been an issue.  2005 backup restored on 2008, no problem.

Going backwards won't work.  2008 backup, restoring onto 2005, won't work.